# How to create a condition to not render my Header component in one of my Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create some rule for my App (React) do not render Header and Footer for my signIn and signUp component.

I am trying to get some variable (like path) and check, but is not working.
I do not want to use the components (Header and Footer) inside others components.

```
<Header/>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path='/signin' component={SignInPage} />
      <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUpPage} />
    </div>
  </Router>
<Footer/>
```

Comment: Give header and footer individually for particular route/components.

Comment: Can you add the whole file, so we can see how your `exports` are set up?

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent `Route` that renders your `Header`, `Footer` and other routes then make a condition based on `pathname`.

```
<Router>
    <Header />
      <Route
        render={props => (  
          <>
            {props.location.pathname !== '/signin' ? <Header /> : null}
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInPage} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUpPage} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </>
        )}
      />
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```